# Accessing Local Website on Mobile (XAMPP)

Tags: android, browser, localhost

I am very much a beginner with this but I am trying to view my local website on a mobile.
I created a 'demo' folder in xampp/htdocs and saved a file called test.php.
When I type in my mobile 192.168.1.83/demo, I can view the file and it displays perfectly.
My question is how do I view my actual website which is called website1 and has a folder in the same location? If I type in 192.168.1.83/website1 it says the web page is not available. Yet typing in the same thing on my PC and it works fine.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: can u access localhost page in mobile?

Comment: Do you mean if I type in just my IP address? If I do that, it takes me to a XAMPP Dashboard.

Comment: ok great...192.168.1.83/website1 in this website1 is any folder or php file?

Comment: In the website1 folder, there are other folders (wp-admin, wp-content, etc) and also lots of php files (wp-config.php, wp-settings.php, etc)

Comment: then access your first php file like this 192.168.1.83/website1/index.php

Comment: This loads the home page (albeit it not very well) but then if I click on a page link, it says the page is not available. Can I not just load it like a normal website like I can on my PC?

Comment: first check you have active internet in mobile through `wifi hotspot`

Comment: Sorry what do you mean? I have active internet, I wouldn't be able to access 192.168.1.83/website1/index.php if I didn't